# Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I am trying to use a local certificate authority and I keep getting an "Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message" error.
Apologies in advance for the complexity of this problem.
You can get the complete sources from github via:

```
git clone git://github.com/ClarkHobbie/ssltest.git
```

And then compile it with

```
mvn package
```

And then run it with

```
java -cp target\ssl-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;lib\netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar SSLTest server
```

and in a different window use

```
java -cp target\ssl-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;lib\netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar SSLTest client
```

When I try running the program, I get to the prompt (like "localhost:6789> ") and I'll try something like "test"  Then I get the error.

If I don't use netty all (see the second block of code) it seems to work.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1434)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1097)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:968)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:902)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Invalid signature on ECDH server key exchange message
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1119)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:284)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1123)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1008)
    ... 18 more
```

Here is the netty version (that throws the exception):

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.ServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler;

import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * Created by Clark on 2/27/2017.
 */
public class SSLTest {
    public static class ServerChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel> {
        private SslContext sslContext;

        public ServerChannelInitializer (SslContext sslContext) {
            this.sslContext = sslContext;
        }

        public void initChannel (NioSocketChannel serverSocketChannel) {
            if (null != sslContext) {
                SslHandler sslHandler = sslContext.newHandler(serverSocketChannel.alloc());
                serverSocketChannel.pipeline().addLast(sslHandler);
            }

            EchoHandler echoHandler = new EchoHandler();
            serverSocketChannel.pipeline().addLast(echoHandler);
        }
    }

    public static class UserInput {
        private static UserInput ourInstance;

        private String prompt;
        private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        public static synchronized void initializeClass (String prompt) {
            if (null == ourInstance) {
                ourInstance = new UserInput (prompt);
            }
        }

        public static UserInput getInstance () {
            return ourInstance;
        }

        private UserInput (String prompt) {
            this.prompt = prompt;

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        }

        public String getLine () throws IOException {
            System.out.print (prompt);
            return bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    }

    public static class ClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
        private SslContext sslContext;

        public ClientInitializer (SslContext sslContext) {
            this.sslContext = sslContext;
        }

        public void initChannel (SocketChannel socketChannel) {
            if (null != sslContext) {
                SslHandler sslHandler = sslContext.newHandler(socketChannel.alloc());
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(sslHandler);
            }

            ClientChannelHandler clientChannelHandler = new ClientChannelHandler();
            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(clientChannelHandler);
        }
    }

    public static class ClientChannelHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            String input = UserInput.getInstance().getLine();

            ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.directBuffer(256);
            ByteBufUtil.writeUtf8(byteBuf, input);
            ctx.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
        }

        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[byteBuf.readableBytes()];
            byteBuf.getBytes(0, buffer);
            String s = new String(buffer);

            System.out.println (s);

            s = UserInput.getInstance().getLine();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
                System.out.println ("quiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            byteBuf = Unpooled.directBuffer(256);
            ByteBufUtil.writeUtf8(byteBuf, s);
            ctx.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
        }

        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            ctx.close();
        }
    }

    public static class EchoHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[byteBuf.readableBytes()];
            byteBuf.getBytes(0, buffer);
            String s = new String(buffer);

            System.out.println("got " + s);

            ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
        }
    }

    public static class CommandLine {
        private String[] argv;
        private int argIndex = 0;
        private String mode = "server";
        private boolean useTls = true;
        private String host = "localhost";
        private int port = 6789;

        public String[] getArgv () {
            return argv;
        }

        public String getArg () {
            if (argIndex >= argv.length)
                return null;

            return argv[argIndex];
        }

        public void advance () {
            argIndex++;
        }

        public String getMode () {
            return mode;
        }

        public void setMode (String mode) {
            this.mode = mode;
        }

        public boolean useTls () {
            return useTls;
        }

        public void setUseTls (boolean useTls) {
            this.useTls = useTls;
        }

        public String getHost () {
            return host;
        }

        public void setHost (String host) {
            this.host = host;
        }

        public int getPort () {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort (int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public CommandLine (String[] argv) {
            this.argv = argv;
            parse();
        }

        public void parse () {
            if (argv.length < 1)
                return;

            if (null != getArg() && getArg().equalsIgnoreCase("nossl")) {
                System.out.println ("Plaintext mode");
                setUseTls(false);
                advance();
            }

            if (null != getArg()) {
                setMode(getArg());
                advance();
            }

            if (null != getArg()) {
                setHost(getArg());
                advance();
            }

            if (null != getArg()) {
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(getArg());
                setPort(temp);
                advance();
            }
        }
    }

    private CommandLine commandLine;

    public CommandLine getCommandLine() {
        return commandLine;
    }

    public SSLTest (CommandLine commandLine) {
        this.commandLine = commandLine;
    }

    public static void closeIgnoreExceptions (Reader reader)
    {
        if (null != reader) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    public static void closeIgnoreExceptions (InputStream inputStream) {
        if (null != inputStream) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    public static void closeIfNonNull (PrintWriter printWriter) {
        if (null != printWriter) {
            printWriter.close();
        }
    }

    public static KeyStore getKeyStore (String filename, String password) {
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load (fileInputStream, password.toCharArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            closeIgnoreExceptions(fileInputStream);
        }

        return keyStore;
    }

    public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey (String filename, String password, String alias) {
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            keyStore.load(fileInputStream, password.toCharArray());
            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return privateKey;
    }


    public void server () {
        try {
            SslContext sslContext = null;

            if (getCommandLine().useTls()) {
                String trustStoreFilename = "truststore";
                String trustStorePassword = "whatever";
                String trustStoreAlias = "ca";

                String keyStoreFilename = "serverkeystore";
                String keyStorePassword = "whatever";
                String keyStoreAlias = "server";

                X509Certificate certificate = getCertificate(trustStoreFilename, trustStorePassword, trustStoreAlias);
                PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(keyStoreFilename, keyStorePassword, keyStoreAlias);
                sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                        .forServer(privateKey, certificate)
                        .build();
            }

            ServerChannelInitializer serverChannelInitializer = new ServerChannelInitializer(sslContext);

            NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            NioEventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

            ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            serverBootstrap.childHandler(serverChannelInitializer);
            serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
            serverBootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);

            System.out.println ("listening on port " + getCommandLine().getPort());

            serverBootstrap.bind(getCommandLine().getPort()).sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static X509Certificate getCertificate (String filename, String password, String alias) {
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        Certificate certificate = null;

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(fileInputStream, password.toCharArray());
            certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return (X509Certificate) certificate;
    }

    public static TrustManagerFactory getTrustManagerFactory (String filename, String password) {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;

        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore(filename, password);
            trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return trustManagerFactory;
    }

    public void client () {
        try {
            String trustStoreFilename = "truststore";
            String trustStorePassword = "whatever";

            SslContext sslContext = null;

            if (getCommandLine().useTls()) {
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = getTrustManagerFactory(trustStoreFilename, trustStorePassword);
                sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                        .forClient()
                        .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
                        .build();
            }

            NioEventLoopGroup nioEventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

            Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();
            clientBootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            clientBootstrap.group(nioEventLoopGroup);
            clientBootstrap.handler(new ClientInitializer(sslContext));
            clientBootstrap.connect(getCommandLine().getHost(), getCommandLine().getPort());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] argv) {
        CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(argv);
        SSLTest sslTest = new SSLTest(commandLine);

        String prompt = commandLine.getHost() + ":" + commandLine.getPort() + "> ";
        UserInput.initializeClass(prompt);

        if (commandLine.getMode().equalsIgnoreCase("server"))
            sslTest.server();
        else if (commandLine.getMode().equalsIgnoreCase("client"))
            sslTest.client();
        else {
            System.err.println ("unknown mode: " + commandLine.getMode());
        }
    }
}
```

I hit the character limit (30,000) on Stack Overflow so you will need to go to GitHub to see the non-netty version.

https://github.com/ClarkHobbie/ssltest2

As to why I am using encryption at all, and why I am using local certificate authorities in particular, I am developing a tool that sits in front of web services and records messages for them.  The tool is clustered, so any messages (POST/PUT/DELETEs) may go across the internet.  To identify nodes and to protect content, encryption is used.  Clients could either get CERTs for all their nodes (expensive, slow and inconvenient) or use a local certificate authority.  See https://ltsllc.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-invalid-signature-problem.html for more details.

Comment: Asking for votes is a no-no here, and will potentially result in downvotes, so I've removed that sentence.  Also, you have not provided code, so it's likely nobody can help you.  The stack trace doesn't seem to include any frames in your code, so it's not clear what's happening.  I think you need to narrow down the problem somewhat.

Comment: Jim thanks for your pointers and suggestions - I added the source files to the question.  I also tried setting the javax.net.ssl.trustStore and javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword properties.  The system uses them (I get a FileNotFoundException if I use a file that does not exist), but still gives me the the invalid signature exception.

Comment: I added a "no netty" program that seems to work.

Comment: This worked with apache mina (up on GitHub at https://github.com/ClarkHobbie/ssltest3).  I have posted a defect to Netty (at https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/6508).

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this problem, try it with core Java and Mina.  If your project works with one of those, use one of them.

I'm the first to say this is not an ideal solution.  What would have been nice would have been something along the lines of "Oh, use option xyz and it will work" but after two weeks of banging my head against this problem, followed by one week on Stack Overflow, followed by one week of working with the folks at Netty, I am ready to use something else.

I made three test programs available on GitHub (ssltest, ssltest2 and ssltest3) and noted that while the program didn't work with Netty, it did work with either core Java or Mina.  The end result was still "This is not a bug."

At this point, my project seems to work with Mina, so I am going with that.  For others: if you don't run into this problem, then by all means, use Netty.  If you do hit this problem, then I would suggest trying it with something else and if that works, using it.